# Trying to build an OpenFrameworks example with CMake

Tags: cmake, openframeworks

I am trying to compile an OpenFrameworks example using CMake. However, I have not been successful so far. I know that asking this question here is a bit of a long shot, but I am desperately looking for a solution.

OpenFrameworks, does not support CMake natively, however I am using a [template](https://github.com/kureta/oF-CLion) developed for building OpenFrameworks using Clion, which is effectively using CMake. Below is an explanation of what procedures I have followed to build the example so far.

**Intro**: OpenFrameworks lives [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/libs). It is a compilation of libs/headers and a stand-alone core. The examples build fine with Xcode but things are complicated when attempting to build without an IDE. The structure of OpenFrameworks is not a usual one, thus passing headers and libs is a bit of a manual work.

Let me explain how the build process of an OpenFrameworks app works (based on the template I have mentioned above):

1) The first `CMakeLists.txt` is designed to live inside the example application folder. The `CMakeLists.txt` script is located [here](https://github.com/kureta/oF-CLion/tree/master/ofApplication).

2) The second `CMakeLists.txt` is designed to pull in all of the OpenFrameworks libs and headers and the `CMakeLists.txt` script is located [here](https://github.com/kureta/oF-CLion/tree/master/openFrameworks).

The idea is that, when you start building the example application, all of the OpenFrameworks bits and pieces will be built as a shared lib and pulled inside. However, this is not working for some reason and I am getting the following error.

```
[ 10%] Performing configure step for 'of_shared'
loading initial cache file /Users/me/dev/cpp_projects/of_sessions/of_3DPrimitivesExample/build/of_shared-    prefix/tmp/of_shared-cache.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/me/dev/cpp_projects/of_sessions/of_3DPrimitivesExample/build/of_shared-prefix/src/of_shared-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make[2]: *** [of_shared-prefix/src/of_shared-stamp/of_shared-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/of_shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like the shared build stage fails for some reason. Unfortunately the convoluted lib/include structure of OpenFrameworks does not help either. Could you please help me to understand what might be going wrong here? I have already submitted an issue with the project maintainer, however, things are moving a bit slow in that community. (OSX, CMake 2.8.12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I got the CMake scripts to work. I just needed a bit of time to understand what those CMake files are doing. I have tweaked and adjusted some bits. Now I am able to build and compile openFrameworks 0.9.3 as a static lib and as a shared lib.

I also succeeded in building and compiling the `3DPrimitivesExample` using both the STATIC and SHARED approaches. All these are done using CMake and VIM. No other IDE (XCode, QtCreator etc.) was used.

Comment: This is a good OFX implementation using CMake: https://github.com/BildPeter/ofxCMake